# php for loop and keep history generating a new array with all the values inside

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

```
$Xn = count($where = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... , $n))/3;
```

where $n is multiple of 3 objects!!!

```
for($i = 1; $i <= ($Xn); $i++) {
      $field[$Xn-$i]     = $where[(3*$i)-3];
      $operator[$Xn-$i]  = $where[(3*$i)-2];
      $value[$Xn-$i]     = $where[(3*$i)-1];
}
```

all i want is to create a big array with all values inside! like this:

```
array($field[0], $operator[0], $value[0], $field[1], $operator[1], $value[1], $field[2], $operator[2], $value[2]...)
```

or 3 small arrays like this:

```
$field_$n = array($field[0], $field[1], $field[2]...)
```

etc..
how can this be done? thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Isn't `$where` already the result you're looking for ? Or are you trying to merge multiple of such arrays together ?

Comment: omg bad description!!

Comment: basically i want an sql statement in which the result depends from the number of values in where array

Comment: $sql = ' select * FROM <table> WHERE' $field[0], $operator[0], $value[0], $field[1], $operator[1], $value[1], $field[2], $operator[2], $value[2]...

Comment: but the values are ? in the statement and during the execution are replaced with actual values!!

Answer (score 0):

sorry guys for bad language and meaning in the question!!, what i had in mind was this!!

```
public function action_X_single($action, $table, $where = array()) {
    $Xn = count($where)/3;
        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');
for($i=1; $i<=$Xn; $i++){
  $field[] = array( 'field'    => $where[(3*$i)-3] );
  $operator[] = array( 'operator' => $where[(3*$i)-2] );
  $value[] = array( 'value'    => $where[(3*$i)-1] );    
}

$sql .= "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE " ;

 for($i=0;$i<$Xn;$i++) 
      {           
        if(($i)==0)
          {
             $sql .= implode(' ', $field[0]) . " " . implode(' ', $operator[0])." ?";
          }  
        else 
          {
             $sql .= " AND ".implode(' ', $field[$i]) . " " . implode(' ', $operator[$i])." ?";                                  
          }        
      }
  for($i=0;$i<$Xn;$i++) { 
           if($i==0) {
               $values .= implode(' ', $value[0]);
           }else {
               $values .= " ".implode(' ', $value[$i]);
           }
        }
            if(!$this->query($sql, explode(' ', $values))->error()) {
                return $this;
            }

    return false;
}
```

and so to get the values from my table i used this:

```
public function get_X_single($table, $where) {
    return $this->action_X_single('SELECT *', $table, $where);
}
```

Comment: i came up with the solution yesterday evening and so to help others i give them my solution